# Child div crosses border of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have multiple div elements in HTML which are nested within one another and are meant to form a frame around the entire document.

It seems like I am not fully grasping the styling properties (I am fairly new to CSS) since the right and bottom parts of the inner divs are actually extending beyond the parent div's dimensions.

```css
@page {
  margin: 0cm;
  /* Set margin on each page */
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dina4frame {
  height: 1050px;
  width: 730px;
}

.bluethin {
  background-color: #0B233D;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.bluebig {
  background-color: #0B233D;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.background {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='dina4frame'>
  <div class='bluethin'>
    <div class='white'>
      <div class='bluebig'>
        <div class='white'>
          <div class='bluethin'>
            <div class='background'>


              <body>

                <h2>Title</h2>

                <div>This is some test text.</div>


              </body>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

I expected to have each inner `div` lying fully within but also fully fill the respective outer one (the 100% height and width properties) and the padding properties making sure there is enough of the outer `div` to see to make it look like a frame around the entire document.

As can be seen from the example, this works on the top and left side but not on the right and bottom, as the inner `divs` are extending beyond their parents.
I tried playing with the height and width percentage but this yields frames which are too big since not controlled by the absolute padding property. And I am sure there must be a very simple and elegant solution to my problem.

What I want is a thin blue line (`2px`) around the whole document (it's meant to be printed on Din A4 later on) with a distance of `5px` to the document's edges,
followed by a white area of `5px` but not overlapping the thin blue line.
Next comes a big blue line (`5px`), similar to the thin one, always keeping a `5px` distance to the edges of the white `div` it sits in. And so on and so forth.

Comment: Please use a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) your HTML markup is invalid. `body` has to be a direct child of the `html` tag and can not be placed inside a div. also it is invalid to place a div outside of the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your paddings are added to the total width of your elements within the div. This causes the elements to have a width > 100%.

You can fix this by adding the following css rules

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

[This article](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) has some additional information on the topic.